# Do I need to study ODE before study difference equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem understand difference equation. I have no prior background in  Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) or PDE. Now I'm studying probability and some chapter show example in difference equation. Do I need to study ODE first in order to understand difference equation well?

after I finish ODE any suggest course on difference equation?

Comment: You know, it might be more useful for you to ask about what you don't understand in that particular example of difference equation. Usually no prior knowledge of ODE or PDE is not needed for understanding difference equations.